# Retrofit -- Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

Tags: java, android, retrofit

my response json like

```
[{"user":"hasan","name":"hasan hamza"},{"user":"hüseyin","name":"hüseyin tırlak"}]
```

and my Class like

```
public class Person {
  public String user;
  public String name;
}
```

and my Retrofit Service interface like

```
  public interface IService {
    @GET(ServiceURLs.USERS)
    Call<List<Person>> getUsers(@Path("operation") String operation);
  }
```

and i call this interface like this

```
    retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ServiceURLs.BASE_SERVICE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
      IService service = retrofit.create(IService.class);

Call<List<Person>> response = service.getUsers(OperationEnum.SHOW.getOperation());
            response.enqueue(new Callback<List<Person>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<List<Person>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    if (response.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.d("Size", response.body().size()+"");

                    } else {
                        // error response, no access to resource?
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    // something went completely south (like no internet connection)
                    Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

when i make this request , it falls onFailure method and it says

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ retrofit

how can i fix it

my configuration

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.damn"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'

}
```

Comment: public interface IService {
    @GET(ServiceURLs.USERS)
    Call<List<Person>> getUsers(@Path("operation") String operation,new Callback<Person> callback);  Can you update this code and try again?
  }

Comment: your error message is basically telling you your response is not what you think it is. enable logging in retrofit and try again.

Comment: mustafasevgi  i think your retrofit version is a little bit old. I checked my code and still error is persist

Comment: njzk2 i know it tells what it is and problem because of it waits { } this kind of json startup but it starts with [ ]

Comment: changing @GET("/users") to @GET("users") can also solve problems. i had the same.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

change the service return type with ResponseBody

```
 @GET(ServiceURLs.USERS)
    Call<ResponseBody> getUsers(@Path("operation") String operation);
```

then

```
Call<LResponseBody> response = service.getUsers(OperationEnum.SHOW.getOperation());
        response.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.d("Size", response.body().size()+"");
                     try {
                    String result = response.body().string();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    List<LinkedTreeMap> persons = gson.fromJson(result, ArrayList.class);
                    personList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (LinkedTreeMap person : persons) {
                        personList.add(gson.fromJson(person.toString(), Person.class));
                    }

                } else {
                    // error response, no access to resource?
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                // something went completely south (like no internet connection)
                Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was because server was response was "null" where I needed an array so what I did was changing the null to an empty array [].
it is best if you do this from server side but if you can't you have to implement another `Converter` as [this link](https://medium.com/@kenkyee/retrofit2-doesnt-handle-empty-content-responses-bef2b33ee8ea) is suggesting.

```
class NullOnEmptyConverterFactory implements Converter.Factory {
@Override public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBody(Type type, Annotation[] 
annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
final Converter<ResponseBody, ?> delegate = retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(this, 
type, annotations);
return new Converter<>() {
  @Override public void convert(ResponseBody body) {
    if (body.contentLength() == 0) return null;
    return delegate.convert(body);
     }
   };
}
}
```

Then to add it:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.endpoint(..)
.addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();
```